# Creating new git branch in eclipse

Tags: git, branch

Every time I try creating a new branch in eclipse, it creates it based off of the current branch.  I want it to create it based off of the master.

I rt-click my overall project (pal)->team->switchTo->new branch
Source->select->master

Even though I'm telling it to create it off of master, it always includes the content from the current branch, which isn't always correct.

How do I correct that, other than doing a command-line, git reset --hard HEAD?  I'd like to create the branch off of master without the content from the current branch.

It looks like I'm doing it correctly, based on instructions I've seen.

Thanks,
Mich

Comment: For simplicity always switch to the original branch first and then start branching of.

Comment: So if I switch to master and then create the new branch it would fix the issue?

Comment: Good question.  Try and see.

Comment: So, did you try? What's the result?

Comment: Eclipse isn't letting me switch to master.  Says branch failed.  Cannot lock /home/pal/workspace/pal-prod/.git/index.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ok.  So I got the errors cleaned up.  I was able to set my branch to master in eclipse.  Then, in eclipse, I created a new branch off of master, but It is still picking up files from my old branch that I was set to before I set to master.

Comment: For me, I created a new git repository therefore I had to again establish a remote connection. Once done, I was able to create a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to pull the changes from master (remote) to the master I set to in my current project.  Then I could see the up-to-date changes.  Then, as suggested above, I would create a new branch.